# If we nonlinearly transform the LS estimates, will they still be unbiased estimates of the true value?

Tags: regression, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, bias, unbiased-estimator

So this is an discussion which came up with a friend/colleague who is a physicist postdoc. He has a bunch of data $(x_i,y_i)$ and wants to fit it to the form $y=e^{ax}$. He uses (weighted) nonlinear least squares and gets $\hat{a}=2$ let's say. So instead of reporting $y=e^{2x}$, he reports $y=e^{x/0.5}$ and tells people to use the second function which will be used for the purposes for interpolation and a little bit of extrapolation. The reason he is changing the functional form is just aesthetic. It just "looks" better to other physicists. But the LS is easier using the first form because the derivative is a lot nicer.

I said, this sounds a little dubious and I argued as follows. $a$ is the actual value which is unknown to us which we want to estimate. We then use LS and (assuming LS is done properly with all of the assumptions satisfied) we get an unbiased estimate $\hat{a}$. Since $E(\hat{a})=a$, we know that $E(\frac{1}{\hat{a}})\neq \frac{1}{a}=b$ because the expectation does not posses functional invariance. So we get this bias and whatever functional form we want to use at the end is the one we should be fitting to.

He says, they are mathematically equivalent. The minimum of SSE is achieved at $a=2$ so it is achieved at $1/a=b=0.5$. What's wrong?

Then we took his data sets (there were three) and ran both types of fits on all of them and the answers are identical to the third decimal place. So now we can't tell if the bias exists or not. Is it the case where the bias exists but is very tiny? Or is it the case where the bias doesn't exist and we just have rounding/computational errors? Which one of us is right? If my argument is wrong, then what is wrong with it? Note that the data is never transformed in any way. WLS is performed on the original data and then the estimates are transformed at the end.